# Can we add values greater than 255 in 8 bit system? If yes then how?

Tags: python

Can we add  values greater than 255 in 8 bit system? If yes then how?

Just not understood! I have seen some websites they introduce overflow concept but it really works? They said it is possible to add values greater than 255 by overflow concept

Comment: It's unclear what you're talking about. 8-bit computers worked with values larger than 255 by using *multiple* bytes, the same humans work with values >9 by using multiple digits. On the other hand, it's possible to do byte arithmetic whose intermediate values exceed 255 if you use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, provided the final result is up to 255. Microprocessor and CPU circuits use this representation for signed numbers

Comment: To expand on Panagiotis's comment, it's unclear what "overflow concept" means. Could you reword/elaborate this bit, or at least link to one such website?

Comment: What does this has to do with Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). In the case of integers like in this example, it's usually known as "bignum".

The idea is to hold the number in an *array* of 8-bit numbers/bytes. When adding two such numbers, you add all the individual bytes, propagating overflows as needed. If there's still overflow when adding the most-significant bytes, you resize the array to hold more bytes.

This is exactly how humans add numbers on pen-and-paper, but with each digit holding 0-255 instead of 0-9. You can also think of it as treating each byte as a "digit" and the array being a variable-length number in base 256.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of bytes and add the elements while using carry bits.

```py
# Function to add two byte arrays of different lengths
def add_byte_arrays(byte_array1, byte_array2):
    len1 = len(byte_array1)
    len2 = len(byte_array2)
    max_len = max(len1, len2)

    # Pad the arrays with zeros to make them of equal length
    byte_array1 = [0] * (max_len - len1) + byte_array1
    byte_array2 = [0] * (max_len - len2) + byte_array2

    carry = 0
    result = []

    # Iterate from the least significant byte to the most significant byte
    for i in range(max_len - 1, -1, -1):
        # Add the corresponding bytes along with the carry
        temp_sum = byte_array1[i] + byte_array2[i] + carry

        # Extract the least significant 8 bits and store it in the result
        result.insert(0, temp_sum & 0xFF)

        # Extract the carry
        # could also be written as carry = temp_sum >> 8 but in a real 8 bit system, the carry is the 9th bit which is discarded
        if temp_sum & 0xFF < max(byte_array1[i], byte_array2[i]):
            carry = 1
        else:
            carry = 0

    # If there is a carry after adding all the bytes, append it to the result
    if carry:
        result.insert(0, carry)

    return result


# Example usage
byte_array1 = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03] 
byte_array2 = [0xFF, 0x01]       # [0x00, 0xFF, 0x01]
number1 = 0x010203
number2 = 0xFF01

result = add_byte_arrays(byte_array1, byte_array2)
number_result = number1 + number2
print([hex(byte) for byte in result])  # Output: [0x01, 0x03, 0x04]
print(hex(number_result)) # To verify the result
```

Output:

```
['0x2', '0x1', '0x4']
0x20104
```